# rooting Samsung Galaxy Note 2

Tags: rooting, samsung-galaxy-note-2

How to root Samsung Galaxy Note 2? I have no experience with rooting. Model number is **GT-N7100**. Android-version **4.1.1**.

Comment: I added your question to our [rooting index](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/1185/16575). You might want to have a look there, maybe another device/method gives you a good starting.

Comment: @PatREllery If you don't say what's wrong with the existing answers, or what further information you'd like, then nobody will add a new answer, and your bounty will automatically go to the existing top answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This will work on the following Galaxy Note 2:

1.**International Galaxy Note 2 GT-N7100**
2.**T-Mobile Galaxy Note 2 SGH-T889**
3.**AT&T Galaxy Note 2 SGH-I317**

Other carriers
[Sprint Galaxy Note 2 SPH-L900](http://galaxynote2root.com/galaxy-note-2-root/how-to-root-sprint-galaxy-note-2-sph-l900/)
[Verizon Galaxy Note 2 SCH-I605](http://galaxynote2root.com/galaxy-note-2-root/how-to-root-verizon-galaxy-note-2-sch-i605/)
(Given a link to video and more description at last sentence)

**Step 1.**

> Put your Galaxy Note 2 into Download mode by turning off your phone
> first then holding down Volume Down, Center Home, and Power buttons
> together.

**Step 2.**

> Once you see the warning screen, hit Volume Up button to enter ODIN
> Download Mode then connect a micro-USB cable from your Note 2 to your
> computer.

**Step 3.**

> If you  have to install [Samsung USB drivers](http://stockroms.net/file/Drivers/Samsung/SAMSUNG_USB_Driver_for_Mobile_Phones.exe)

**Step 4.**

> Next, download [GalaxyNote2Root.zip](http://downloadandroidrom.com/file/GalaxyNote2/rooting/GalaxyNote2Root.zip)

**Step 5.**

> Unzip the files. Next, open up the ODIN program by double-clicking on
> the .exe file.

**Step 6.**

> You should see a yellow-highlighted COM box with a random number. If
> you don’t see it, double-check your Windows drivers (the Samsung USB
> drivers you installed in Step 3) and unplug, plug your Note 2 back
> into your computer.

**Step 7.**

> DO NOT TOUCH ANYTHING ELSE and click on “PDA” button then find the
> file cwm6-root-note2.tar(in unzipped folder).

**Step 8.**

> Hit Start and let ODIN flash the custom CWM Recovery. When it’s done,
> your Galaxy Note 2 will reboot and you should have a fully rooted
> Galaxy Note 2.

Your phone will boot into newly installed CWM Recovery automatically once and install Superuser app and su binaries then reboot.
You should find a new Superuser app called “SuperSU”.
You can easily verify you have root by downloading Titanium Backup app (free on Play Store) and running it. (a Pop up will appear)

In [here](http://galaxynote2root.com/galaxy-note-2-root/how-to-root-galaxy-note-2-easiest-method/) they described with details and video that "How to root Note 2" .
You have to just go for the carrier name, under which you are now.

**Good Luck**

**NOTE:I'm not responsible if you mess up your phone. Make sure you know what you are doing before following any instructions. Go [here](http://galaxynote2root.com/galaxy-note-2-faq/) .Just read it.**

Comment: Just to reiterate something on the above: read, read and then read more. Things often go wrong, I've made some seriouisly basic mistakes and it's always a fright when an expensive piece of tech fails to boot! Make backups on your SD card, then copy the backups on your PC (nandroid backup in custom recovery). You never know when you'll need them!

Answer (score 0):

My GT-N7100 was rooted successfully after watching [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?list=UUA2XWPjQBJVScn7wQjeqMqA&feature=player_embedded&v=NFHZ535L7is) and following [these steps](http://galaxynote2root.com/galaxy-note-2-root/how-to-root-galaxy-note-2-easiest-method/).

Answer (score 0):

I've used the following guide on XDA Developers:
http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1923956

And did the same for the S3 (for which they also have a toolkit and a thread)