# How to root samsung galaxy note2 n7100?

Tags: rooting

I want to root my samsung galaxy note2 n7100. I saw lots of tutorials on internet. But no tutorial give me a 100% guarantee. :( can anyone help me to root my mobile?

Comment: You can never get a 100% guarantee from anywhere. You gotta try the one which is close to surety and if you run into any problem, seek help here.

Comment: See: [rooting Samsung Galaxy Note 2](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/39382/16575)

Answer (score 1):

Google This exactly

> CF Autoroot Note 2 "n7100" [Insert Version Os Here, IE: 4.4.2]

Also Try

> Casual root "n7100" [Insert Version Os Here, IE: 4.4.2]

Match your OS version to the thread, and it should work.

Note
 1. Back up stuff, like everything will be deleted.
 2. Wipe the phone before starting it (Some software can interfere and mess it up.

To increate your od
Easiest way for Note 2, If you havent updated in a while,
As for specific thread and links - It will take some searching. I dont have one saved.
But once you find it its easy

Comment: "Google this and that" is not the kind of answers we favour on SE. You should include the essentials, and a link for references.

Comment: Useless with these models; Cause the links and its relevance will change, and theres seldom reliable statics. So I put "Google for" and [An exact keyword] because of its dynamic nature.

Comment: No problems to mention that along, but the recommended solution should be on our site still.

Answer (score 0):

i suggest you, use autoroot for this phone :

> [download for 4.4.2](http://download.chainfire.eu/264/CF-Root/CF-Auto-Root/CF-Auto-Root-t03g-t03gxx-gtn7100.zip)

add to odin, then flash !
and finally, install last version of **Super su** 
or use this :

> [How do I root my Android device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1184/how-do-i-root-my-android-device)

there's not any guarantee for badmistake or other something, only you & your phone.!